# How can I treat the type of a subclass's member as it's own type rather than it's parent type in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have this class

```
class Node {
    Node parent;
    int rank;

    public Node() {
        this.parent = this;
        this.rank = 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to create subclasses of `Node`, but I want `parent` to be the same type as it's corresponding type.

How can I do this?

Ultimately, I am trying to create a special UnionFind data structure. I implemented the `find` and `merge` functions for the data structures. However, I want to extend this and add more functionality. I would like to add the member `V value` to `Node` and record the minimum value of each set. For me, the best way to do this is to create a subclass of Node. Would there be a better way to this?

Comment: This has been answered plenty of times. Literally answered this a few days ago. Use generics for a quick-fix: `Node<T extends Node<T>>`

Comment: Corollary: [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).